# I want to generate random number in android but exclude some that end with zero

Tags: android

```
            int min = 651;
            int max = 999;
            Random r = new Random();    
            do  {
                    final   int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min; 
                } 
            while(i1 %10 == 0);
```

I want to generat random number in this(651 to 999) range but don't want 660,670,680 so on which ends with zero or in middle(707,805)  so help me in this case 
in this code error:- i1 in while loop  is not local variable

Comment: Perhaps you should identify that this is homework, because this is clearly a basic programming question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows. All you have to do is, loop until you find a number that is not divisible by 10.

```
int min = 651;
int max = 999;
Random r = new Random();
int randomNum;    
while(true){
    randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    if(randomNum%10!=0){
        break;
    }
}
//now you have the required random number
```

**What's wrong in your code**

What you had done was right, apart from accessing a local variable outside of its context. You have to declare i1 outside of the while loop's context. Also, remember, **a final** int cannot be modified once assigned. In your case this doesn't affect since it is in the context of the while loop.

```
int i1; //this should come here. 
do  {
     i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min; // no final anymore
} 
while(i1 %10 == 0);
```